# failed to load (hello.component.ts )

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new to `angular` and am facing issue when loading the page. For the issue kindly refer to the screenshot.

**hello.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpFeb.png)

Comment: Run npm install in terminal.Then if it didn't work well go for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your module does have imported your component as below first.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
    HelloComponent  
  ],
```